# Card Game - Problems with selection sort of players hand

Tags: java, oop, sorting

We are making a simple 52 card game. We are having a lot of trouble dealing, shuffling and storing cards. 5 cards should be dealt to each player. The game is similar to Hearts but each player only gets 5 cards. This is our code so far:

```
    int[] deck = new int[52];
    String[] suits = { "Spades", "Hearts", "Diamonds", "Clubs" };
    String[] ranks = { "A ", "2 ", "3 ", "4 ", "5 ", "6 ", "7 ", "8 ",
            "9 ", "10", "J ", "Q ", "K " };


    // Initialize the cards
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++)
        deck[i] = i;

    // Shuffle the cards
    for (int i = 0; i < deck.length; i++) {

        // Generate an index randomly

        int index = (int) (Math.random() * deck.length);
        int temp = deck[i];
        deck[i] = deck[index];
        deck[index] = temp;

    }

    // Display the first five cards
    System.out.println("player 1 has:");
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
    String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
    String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
    selectionSort(deck);
    System.out.println("Card number " + deck[i] + " : " + rank + " of "
                + suit);

    }

    int player1[] = deck;

    // Display the first five cards
    System.out.println("\n" + "player 2 has:");
    for (int i = 5; i < 10; i++) {
    String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
    String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];
    System.out.println("Card number " + deck[i] + " : " + rank + " of "
                + suit);

    }

    int player2[] = deck;

    // Display the first five cards

    System.out.println("\n" + "player 3 has:");
    for (int i = 10; i < 15; i++) {
    String suit = suits[deck[i] / 13];
    String rank = ranks[deck[i] % 13];

    System.out.println("Card number " + deck[i] + " : " + rank + " of "
    + suit );

    }
    int player3[] = deck;

}

public static void selectionSort(int[] deck) {

    for (int i = 52; i < deck.length - 1; i--){
    int currentMax = deck[i];
    int currentMaxIndex = i;

    for (int j = i + 1; j < deck.length; j++) {
        if (currentMax > deck[j]) {
            currentMax = deck[j];
            currentMaxIndex = j;
        }}
    if (currentMaxIndex != i) {
        deck[currentMaxIndex] = deck[i];
        deck[i] = currentMax;

        }
    }
}
 }
```

Comment: _We are really having trouble_ --> Be more specific...

Comment: If you use a `List` to store your cards, you can use the `sort` and the `shuffle` methods of the `Collections` class to sort / shuffle your deck.

Comment: If you do your own shuffle, do it right - see [Fisher–Yates shuffle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle). However, as pointed out in an earlier comment, it would be much better to use the Collections shuffle.

Answer (score 2):

Make "card" an object.

That would vastly simplify your code. Instead of having a array of strings, just have 2 chars for rank and suit in each card object.

Then you can make "deck" an array of cards.

Make players have an object too, with their own array of cards.

If you want, you can even make deck an object too, that way you can just call

```
deck.shuffle();
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok I think this will help you in the long run. I looked at your code for about two seconds and saw it has some serious structural problems. Here is where you should start at:

```
public enum Suit
{
     CLUBS, SPADES, HEARTS, DIAMONDS
}
```

---

```
public enum Value
{
    TWO, THREE, FOUR, FIVE, SIX, SEVEN, EIGHT, NINE, TEN, JACK, QUEEN, KING, ACE
}
```

---

```
public class Card
{
    private Value value;
    private Suit suit;


    public Card(Suit theSuit, Value theValue)
    {
        suit = theSuit;
        value = theValue;
    }

    public Value getValue()
    {
        return value;
    }

    public Suit getSuit()
    {
        return suit;
    }
}
```

Now once we have that base established we can also say that a hand and a deck are very similar because they are both a stack of cards so we should build a base for them:

```
public class CardStack
{
    public ArrayList<Card> cards;

    public CardStack()
    {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
    }

    public Card draw()
    {
        if(cards.size() > 0)
        {
            Card card = cards.objectAt(cards.size() - 1);
            cards.remove(card);
            return card;
        }

        return null;
    }

    public void addCard(Card card)
    {
        cards.add(card);
    }
}
```

Now the rest is up to you, Deck and Hand should both extend CardStack. Sorry for the extremely long answer but this will help you in the long run. If the structure is wrong the program will never run properly. You should obviously have a Player class and it should have an instance of Hand and your Game class or whatever should have an instance of deck. The deck should have a shuffle and reset method, Hand really only needs like a clear meathod. I hope this helped you out! Good Luck!

---

UPDATE

Here is more on enums if you don't know what they are:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html

Here is some general OOP information:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/concepts/

If you read both of those your code will dramatically improve. If you need more help I can post more code.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by other people in the comments and answers, the design can be improved by making it object oriented.

I think I understand the intention: first create a deck an shuffle it. After that, the first 5 elements of `deck` represent the hand of player 1. The next 5 elements represent the hand of player 2, and so on.

While printing the hand of player 1, inside the loop, `selectionSort` is called. The method `selectionSort` sorts the complete `deck` array. A closer inspection of `selectionSort` shows me it does nothing! After fixing `selectionSort` you will see in the output is a random card followed by the last four cards of the last suit (clubs).

I assume you attempt to sort the hand of player 1 by calling `selectionSort` within the loop that prints the hand of player 1.

If my assumption is correct, you should modify `selectionSort` so that you can specify an lower and upper index that specifies which part of the array should be sorted. It could look like this:

```
public static void selectionSort(int[] deck, int start, int end) {

    for (int i = start; i<end; i++) {
        int currentMax = deck[i];
        int currentMaxIndex = i;

        for (int j = i + 1; j < end; j++) {
            if (currentMax < deck[j]) {
                currentMax = deck[j];
                currentMaxIndex = j;
            }
        }
        if (currentMaxIndex != i) {
            deck[currentMaxIndex] = deck[i];
            deck[i] = currentMax;
        }
    }
}
```

To sort the cards for player 1, call `selectionSort(deck, 0, 5);`. For player 2 call `selectionSort(deck, 5, 10);`. For player 3 call `selectionSort(deck, 10, 15);`